# How do I set the taint mode in a perl script with a '#!/usr/bin/env perl'- shebang?

Tags: perl, shebang, taint

how do I set the taint mode in a perl script with a

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

shebang?

Comment: It helps if you can't predict the location of the perl binary (/usr/bin or /usr/local/bin). http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=716740 - I guess the question is whether you can predict the location of env...

Comment: On my PC I use /usr/local/bin/perl and on my netbook /usr/bin/perl. So with /usr/bin/env perl I don't have to change my perl-scripts. And I suppose they will ship the next release of my OS with perl-version 5.10.1, so maybe I will use on my PC again the onboard-perl with /usr/bin/perl and there too I won't have to change my shebangs.

Comment: Gavin, the location of `env` is standardised.

Comment: @daxim unless you use OpenServer 5.0.6 (SCO) or Unicos 9.0.2 (Cray)  ;-) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-bang#Portability

Comment: @Sinan, if you ever use perlbrew and have multiple Perls installed on your system, then using `/usr/bin/env perl` is a godsend

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass the PERL5OPT environment variable on the shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env PERL5OPT=-T perl
```

This seems all rather backwards to me.

Another option, is to re-execute the script under taint mode if you detect it's not on:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

warn 'Taint mode is '.(${^TAINT} ? 'on' : 'off'); # For debugging

exec($^X,'-T',$0,@ARGV) unless ${^TAINT};

# do stuff under taint mode here
```

Obviously, this is a major startup performance hit.

Comment: You cannot actually specify a variable in a shebang with /usr/bin/env.  Doing so will cause env to execve itself in an infinite loop, never even getting to the command requested.  I tested this against both Linux and FreeBSD.

Comment: Yes - it seems to be only OS-X that currently supports the first incantation.

Answer (score 3):

Since taint mode can only be enabled via the `-T` flag, and `env` won't accept any flags in a shebang line, your best option is to run the program via `perl -T script.pl` rather than executing the script directly.

If you absolutely need to enforce taint mode in the shebang, you could make a `taintperl` script somewhere in your PATH (e.g. /usr/local/bin) with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/env perl -T
```

Then in your Perl script, have

```
#!/usr/bin/env taintperl
```

Comment: On many OSs, you cannot use an interpreted script as a script interpreter. You would have to do this in a compiled language, e.g. C

Comment: @GavinBrock That is true for the program mentioned immediately after the `#!`. Here, it's `/usr/bin/env`, which is compiled. In turn, `env` doesn't care about whether `taintperl` is a compiled program or not.