# Is there a `use` equivalent of `-T` (taint) used in shebang?

Tags: perl, taint

In the past I placed the Perl options in the "shebang line", like `#!/usr/bin/perl -w`, but then I discovered that

- the options will be ignored when the program is run via `perl your_perl_file`
- there is `use warnings;` that does not have the disadvantage listed above

Unfortunately there does not seem to exist an equivalent like `use taint;` for `-T` (taint mode).
Specifically when debugging such feature would be useful avoiding messages like

> "-T" is on the #! line, it must also be used on the command line at ./server.pl line 1.

Did I miss something, or are there reasons why such does not exist (in Perl 5.18)?

Comment: Options on the shebang line are not ignored (in general) when invoked as `perl your_file`. In particular, -w is processed. `-T` is a bit of special case, because it needs to be detected and acted upon very early in the start up process. I am not aware of any workaround for this.

Comment: I only found https://stackoverflow.com/a/2529070/6607497, but that won't help.

Answer (score 2):

It's too late by then. If you use `use`, you're searching `@INC`, and the contents of `@INC` are controller by `-T`.

What you could do:

```perl
die( "$0 must be run with taint enabled (`-T`).\n" ) if !${^TAINT};
```

Comment: Well, it's probably formally correct to be unable to enable it in run-time, but for a practical point of view it's better to enable `-T` late rather than not enabling it at all. I mean: Most danger is probably not from the execution environment (like PATH), but from program input (e.g. considering some network services).

Comment: No, that's only one use-case for `-T`. Can't break the feature because *you* don't care about the other use-cases.

Comment: Actually what would break, assuming there would be a `use taint` that would magically re-exec Perl with `-T` for that program? The security gap would be up to processing `use taint` and re-executing Perl.

Comment: Without `-T`, you can literally get Perl to execute code before the first line of your program is compiled using `PERL5OPT`.